# cpanel: Reply "550 No Such User" with a Default Address

Tags: cpanel, catch-all

In cpanel, if I do not set up "Domain Fowarding", a 550 "No Such User" bounces email to non-existent email addresses on my domain.

If I do set up Domain Forwarding, email to a non-existent address is forwarded to the mailbox I designate in the Domain Forwarding.

I would like to use Domain Forwarding,  but set up specific addresses to reply with 550 No Such User. How can I achieve this in cpanel?

The goal is to bounce mail to addresses that have become spam targets, while having a "catch-all" address for all other mail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be as simple as (after setting up Domain Forwarding), adding a forwarder for the specific address we want to bounce, and, instead of selecting a mailbox to forward to, selecting "fail" with a configurable message that defaults to "No such person at this address."

Comment: When you are allowed, please accept your own answer to help others in future.